# How to load custom Linux kernel module that is not Linux kernel version dependant using RPM

Tags: kernel-modules, modprobe

I have a 3rd party library which provides a kernel module (`module.ko`) and is required to be loaded automatically on bootup. However, `module.ko` is not tied to a specific version of the Linux kernel and can work across many versions.
Note I do not have the source for `module.ko`; it comes precompiled.

I am creating an RPM package for this 3rd party library and therefore creating a SPEC file.

My first approach was to use `lib/modprobe.d`, `lib/modules-load.d` and `lib/modules/$(uname -r)` to automatically load `module.ko` on bootup. This works fine; however, I do not want to have to reinstall my package every time I upgrade the Linux kernel. This is because, in the SPEC file, `module.ko` is copied to `lib/modules/$(uname -r)`,
where `$(uname -r)` is the current kernel version.

The second approach is to create a service that loads the kernel on bootup using `insmod`. This avoids `modprobe` altogether, as `modprobe` requires the kernel to be copied to `lib/modules/$(uname -r)`.

My question is whether the second approach is the only way to achieve this, or if there is a better one?

Comment: The `insmod` approach looks to be the easiest one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a service to do the `insmod` you could provide a `/lib/modprobe.d/mymodule.conf` with the line

```
install mymodule insmod /path/to/mymodule.ko
```

---

I tried this and it worked ok on a fedora 22 using as an example the existing `slip` module.

```
$ cd /lib/modules/4.2.8-200.fc22.x86_64/extra/drivers/net/slip/
$ lsmod|grep slip
$ sudo modprobe slip
$ lsmod|grep slip
slip                   20480  0
slhc                   20480  1 slip
$ sudo rmmod slip
$ lsmod|grep slip
$ sudo mv slip.ko.xz ~
$ sudo modprobe slip
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'slip': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter
$ sudo sh -c 'echo install slip insmod /home/meuh/slip.ko.xz >/lib/modprobe.d/mymodule.conf'
$ sudo modprobe slip
$ lsmod|grep slip
slip                   20480  0
slhc                   20480  1 slip
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however this is what I tried in approach 1. The problem I found is to call `/lib/modprobe.d/mymodule.conf` you need to call `modprobe mymodule`, and to call `modprobe mymodule` you need `mymodule.ko` to be copied over to `lib/modules/$(uname -r)` which is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: I just tried my suggestion and it worked ok. See my updated answer. Note that the .conf calls `insmod` not modprobe.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I followed your steps and it worked! I must have done something wrong before...